# Display "In Stock" notice for WooCommerce variations with no Managed Stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

I need help for a particular situation. In WooCommerce, if "Manage Stock" is enabled for a simple product or variation, then a notification is being displayed in the product page => such as [this example][1]

However, if "Manage Stock" is not enabled, then there is no notification which I find it a pity because I still want to inform my customers that it's precisely in stock even if I don't manage the stock quantities.

I've found the below code. For simple products, it works without any problem. However, for variable product, this message is being displayed even *before* that a variation is selected. This is of course not okay, this code should be displayed only after that a variation is selected.

Can someone help me to fix this? For variable products, this message should only be displayed *after* that a particular variation is selected.

I've made a video capture to be a bit more illustrative : https://sgevcen.tinytake.com/tt/NDQzNTU2OF8xNDAyNTU2NA

```
function mycustom_shop_display_stock() {

    global $product;

    if ( !$product->get_manage_stock() && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo '<p class="stock in-stock">In Stock</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'mycustom_shop_display_stock', 11 );


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFnN1.png
```

Comment: @7uc1f3r Not really a duplicate as the question and my answer are slightly different from the mentioned thread.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I see what you mean, [`$product->get_availability();`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L3401-L3423). is used in `wc_get_stock_html` function, 
I don't know if one has an advantage over the other? change text against html output, I believe it can do both. Thanks for pointing this out to me

Comment: NOT a duplicate but related: [Display custom stock message if “Manage Stock” is not enabled in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749190/display-custom-stock-message-if-manage-stock-is-not-enabled-in-woocommerce)

Comment: @7uc1f3r Yes it's related but this thread is about variations of a variable product problem… Your code is fine in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749190/display-custom-stock-message-if-manage-stock-is-not-enabled-in-woocommerce as I have already used those related filters in a lot of answers too. I have added your link in my answer (and +1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead that should allow to display your custom stock availability only for the variations of a variable product (and also on simple products):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_stock_html', 'filter_wc_get_stock_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_wc_get_stock_html( $html, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_type('variable') && ! $product->get_manage_stock() && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $html = '<p class="stock in-stock">' . __( "In Stock", "woocommerce" ) . '</p>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To exclude some product categories use the following (related to your comment):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_stock_html', 'filter_wc_get_stock_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_wc_get_stock_html( $html, $product ) {
    // Here define the product categories to be excluded (can be term Ids, slugs or names)
    $terms_excl = array('hoodies', 'albums');

    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if ( ! $product->is_type('variable') && ! $product->get_manage_stock() && $product->is_in_stock()
    && ! has_term( $terms_excl, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $html = '<p class="stock in-stock">' . __( "In Stock", "woocommerce" ) . '</p>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related thread: [Display custom stock message if "Manage Stock" is not enabled in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749190/display-custom-stock-message-if-manage-stock-is-not-enabled-in-woocommerce)

Comment: In this topic, is it possible to exclude some products (belonging to a product categorya, cateogryb and categoryc) to be impacted by this code?

Comment: I'm new in this plateform, so please apologize if I'm not familiar with all the way it works. I have just "accepted the answer" and I also "said thanks" :) but in fact I'm not using the above code, I'm using this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749190/display-custom-stock-message-if-manage-stock-is-not-enabled-in-woocommerce/60758073#60758073 so the exclude should be done on this code

Comment: I've just tested the code provided for the excluding but it doesn't seem to work. You can check this video capture in which I show that (cache cleared) : https://sgevcen.tinytake.com/tt/NDQ0NzE1OF8xNDA2MjMwOA I've tried to define the categories by slugs & ID but both didn't change anything. The notification is well displayed for all but the exclude isn't working. Could you help please? Thanks

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, did you have any time to check my answer below? Thanks

Comment: @gevcen That was a stupid mistake in my code… It works now. Could ou please remove your answer and clean all old comments, as the related code is just an addition that has nothing to do with the original question. thank you.

Comment: I've deleted the other comment and I've tested your corrected code => it works just AWESOME, thank you for your help!