# Display custom stock message if “Manage Stock” is not enabled and exclude certain product categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

I'm using [Display custom stock message if “Manage Stock” is not enabled in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758073/11987538)

The code is successfully adding a custom notice when a product is in stock but "Manage Stock" is not enabled.

However, I would like to exclude the products from "categorya", "categoryb" and "categoryc" (defined by their slugs) to be impacted by this code.

Anyone can help me exclude products from these categories to be impacted by this code?

Comment: **1)** Stackoverflow is not a 'free write code for me service', therefore you should include the attempt you made to modify the code. **2)** Please mention the source in your question if you use already existing code. **3)** If you have found a helpful answer, an [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) would be appreciated. **4)** Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62778565/11987538) contains an answer but has not yet been [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I tried to make attempts but I didn't manage to make it. And for the previous post that I made, I did make an attempt, so you can't just say that I'm just looking for free code writing, I'm here for help. Can you please re-open the ticket?

Comment: **1)** I have not closed your question, but I understand why it has been closed. **2)** If you want your question to be reopened, you need to adjust it. If it then meets the guidelines, it will eventually be reopened. **3)** in my previous comments 
I mentioned 4 points, your reaction seems to relate only to the first point, 
so please read ALL the points I mentioned before.